# Make Azure Keyvault secrets available in entire pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In order to access my secret from the keyvault, I run

```
        - task: AzureKeyVault@2
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: $(KEYVAULT_SC_DEV)
            KeyVaultName: $(KEYVAULT_NAME_DEV)
            SecretsFilter: APICREDENTIALS
            RunAsPreJob: true
```

which works fine.

However, I have multiple jobs and am now facing the trouble of having to repeat these lines too many times.

So, is there a way to tell Azure Devops that this secret should be set globally for each job/stage/step.. etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want these secrets available to multiple pipelines** one way would be to use the library variables

[image]

And reference these in your pipeline
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-variable-group

**If you want these secrets available to multiple stages/jobs/steps within the same pipeline** one way would be to create a pipeline variable

```
variables:
  secretValue: ''

jobs:
- job: RetrieveSecret
  steps:
  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(KEYVAULT_SC_DEV)
      KeyVaultName: $(KEYVAULT_NAME_DEV)
      SecretsFilter: APICREDENTIALS
      OutputVariable: secretValue
```

Here the RetrieveSecret job retrieves the secret from the Key Vault and stores it in the secretValue pipeline variable.Once the secret has been stored in the pipeline variable, you can reference it from any job or task in your pipeline by using the $(pipelineVariableName) syntax.

The caveat here is that pipeline variables are scoped to a specific job, if you wanted to use the same variable across different jobs then you need to pass this value to the next job sort of like below

```
jobs:
- job: Job1
  steps:
  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(KEYVAULT_SC_DEV)
      KeyVaultName: $(KEYVAULT_NAME_DEV)
      SecretsFilter: APICREDENTIALS
      OutputVariable: secretValue
- job: Job2
  inputs:
    secretInput: $(secretValue)
  steps:
  - task: SomeTask
    inputs:
      secret: $(secretInput)
```

Comment: you sure that your second approach works? In my case, the secretValue is not getting overwritten by the AzureKeyVault secret. It only seems to work within the same job or am I missing something?

Comment: @Bennimi have updated to include passing the output variable to the next job

Comment: thanks! that´s the missing piece! I ended up implementing your first solution. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make Azure Keyvault secrets available across multiple jobs or stages with `AzureKeyVault@2`task, you can use outputs in a different stages.

For example, I’ve set secret `password` in my KeyVault.

Across multiple jobs:

```
 variables:
     # map the output variable from A into this job
     password-job-b: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['ouputvariable.mypassword'] ]
```

Across multiple stage:

```
variables:
      # map the output variable from A into this job
      password-stage-two: $[ stageDependencies.One.A.outputs['ouputvariable.mypassword'] ]
```

Across whole job :

```
 - task: AzureKeyVault@2
   RunAsPreJob: true ## Make the secret(s) available to the whole job
```

Full yaml sample:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: One
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - task: AzureKeyVault@2
      inputs:
       azureSubscription: ‘your subscription‘
       KeyVaultName: ‘your keyvault name’
       SecretsFilter: '*'
       RunAsPreJob: true
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=mypassword;isOutput=true]$(password)"'
      name : ouputvariable
  - job: B
    dependsOn : A 
    variables:
     # map the output variable from A into this job
     password-job-b: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['ouputvariable.mypassword'] ]
    steps:
    - script: echo this is password :$(password-job-b) # this step uses the mapped-in variable
- stage: Two
  variables:
      # map the output variable from A into this job
      password-stage-two: $[ stageDependencies.One.A.outputs['ouputvariable.mypassword'] ]
  jobs:
  - job: C
    steps:
    - script: echo this is password :$(password-stage-two) # this step uses the mapped-in variable
```

Result across multiple jobs:
[image: Result across multiple jobs]

Result across multiple stages:
[image: Result across multiple stages]

**UPDATE**

When `issecret` is set to true, the value of the variable will be saved as secret .

```
script: 'echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=mypassword;isOutput=true;issecret=true]$(password)"'
```

Comment: It works, though, the secret is not encrypted anymore. Is there a way to guarantee encryption all the way?

Comment: @Bennimi You can set `issecret = true` to keep the secret encrypted. Updated my answer Hope it can help you.

Comment: this works, thanks. I ended up using the other solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

We can use "**variable groups**" to pass the values into a YAML pipeline, which we can make available across all.

Steps1:
**Store Key vault key values into Variable Groups**
how to use [keyvault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Step2:
**Use that Variable group into any pipelines**
Here is the reference: [tutorial](https://thomasthornton.cloud/%29%20%28https://thomasthornton.cloud/2021/06/24/storing-and-retrieving-secrets-in-azure-keyvault-with-variable-groups-in-azure-devops-pipelines/) from Thomas Thornton